# writing data form loops to matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix

ı need help. I have Form x (5000 samples) and FormY (5000 samples). I draw samples (sample size differentiate between 10-400) from X and Y forms and I equte these forms in R. But I have a problem. I want to write equated scores ( for each sample size and for 100 replications) to matrix But ı couldnt. If you help me, ı will be glad...
My code:

```
x<-read.table("X_Top_25_SANS_0.csv")
y<-read.table("Y_sum25_SANS_0_SD0.1.csv")
data_xy<-data.frame(x,y)
ii<-c(10,15,25,50,75,100,125,150,200,250,400) # Sample sizes
jj<-c(rep(1:100)) # replication
################# örneklem döngüleri ######################
for(i in 1:length(ii)){ #sample loop

  for(j in 1:length(jj)){ #replication loop

    x_rep<-sample(data_xy[,1],ii[i],replace=TRUE) #drawing sample
    y_rep<-sample(data_xy[,2],ii[i],replace=TRUE)
xy_lin=(sd(y_rep)/sd(x_rep))*x_rep + mean(y_rep) - (mean(x_rep)*(sd(y_rep)/sd(x_rep)))
}}
```

**I want to write "xy_lin" to matrix**

Answer (score 0):

As I said in my comment, it is difficult to understand the problem without a reproducable example, and I am not sure I understand the formula correctly that you apply in the loop, so my solution is based on some guesses. Anyway, try this:

```
 data_xy<-data.frame(x=rnorm(5000),y=rnorm(5000)) # random data 
 ii<-c(10,15,25,50,75,100,125,150,200,250,400)
 jj<-c(rep(1:100))

 xy_lin <- matrix(NA, nrow=length(ii), ncol=length(jj)) # create the results matrix

 for(i in 1:length(ii)){ 
   for(j in 1:length(jj)){
     x_rep<-sample(data_xy[,1],ii[i],replace=TRUE)
     y_rep<-sample(data_xy[,2],ii[i],replace=TRUE)
     xy_lin[i,j] <- sd(y_rep)/sd(x_rep)*mean(x_rep)+mean(y_rep) - mean(x_rep)*(sd(y_rep)/sd(x_rep))
   }}
```

Note that I changed your formula from `...*x_rep` to `...*mean(x_rep)`, since I think that this is what you had in mind. But I might be mistaken, so please be aware of that.